# Bootstrap markdown not working as expected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, markdown

I am trying to use the Bootstrap markdown as documented [here](http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/). This is what I have come up with: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejhvkacm/).

HTML:

```
<textarea name="content" data-provide="markdown" rows="10" id = "foo"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#foo").markdown({autofocus:false,savable:true});
});
```

It is a pretty basic fiddle with just a text area and the markdown code, but as you can see, it does not work as expected, the buttons are not showing up correctly, and preview is not working.

How do I fix it to work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For Bootstrap Markdown to work load Bootstrap files too:

   ```
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   ```
2. To fix the preview load three more dependencies:

   - https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js
   - https://github.com/chjj/marked
   - https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown

It is mentioned in small letters at the bottom of the main page.

Example with preview in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejhvkacm/5/)

---

**Updated** with preview fix

Comment: Aha, right. I thought I was probably missing something, but could not find any mention of this in the markdown documentation (perhaps they expected its users to know it). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AttitudeMonger You're welcome :) I looked also to see and couldn't find it. Usually its mentioned somewhere in the docs

Comment: A man was waiting for an answer. A man thanks you for your answer. Valas bootstrapis!

Comment: Ha ha. BTW, this still does not work as expected. Clicking the bold button and previewing it shows weird results.

Comment: Any idea why the preview is not working? How to fix that?

Comment: Yes I see there's some problem with the preview. Wait I will take a look at it a couple of minutes :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116889/discussion-between-jaqen-hghar-and-attitudemonger).